# Installing Helidon on WSL

Tags: helidon

I would like to install Helidon SE  on WSL Ubunto. I cannot find the steps in the documentation located at helidon.io. Can someone provide these or send me a link to the instructions? I've searched Google to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hi just place it in your `/usr/local/bin/`:

```
sudo curl -LJ -o /usr/local/bin/helidon \
https://github.com/oracle/helidon-build-tools/releases/latest/download/helidon-cli-linux-amd64 && \
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/helidon
```

[image]

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Helidon in both of its flavors is a set of libraries that you use via Maven.  I think [the documentation covers this](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/#/about/03_prerequisites) pretty well.

Comment: Thank you. I was confused and actually wanted to install the Helidon CLI. This can be downloaded at https://github.com/oracle/helidon-build-tools/releases/download/2.1.0/helidon-cli-linux-amd64.